# Is there a current bug with FireFox 3 relating to clearing a float and it ignoring negative margins?

Tags: css, firefox, css-float, margin

I've been doing some Googling, but haven't really found a straight answer. I'm curious to know if Firefox 3 has a bug when trying to apply a negative margin to a div that is either clearing a float or contains another element being floated?

Firefox seems to ignore the negative margin, but Web-kit browses respect it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I read a few related snippets on `display: inline-block;` and after adding that to the div I am applying the negative margin, `margin-top: -10px;` it worked.